# recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer) at android mobile connecting to Azure

Tags: android, azure, asp.net-web-api

An in production Android mobile system has been using a connection to an .net webAPI hosting on Azure for 3 months without issue.  Just last weekend (7 april 2014) all the mobiles connecting to the API were failing with the recvfrom failure.

Other than Summertime changing over, neither the API, the android code, the handset mobile provider or the database has been touched.

Can anyone tell me why this might happen and is it an issue at the handset or at the API/Azure?

The issue happens whether on WIFI or mobile network.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this will tell something http://blog.gluwer.com/2014/03/story-of-eaddrinuse-and-econnreset-errors/

Comment: I will try a few things on this blog.  I'm not sure how jnode relates to my httpConnection in Android?  Any idea?